# Error when applying if statement in Google Analytics Data Get Call

Tags: php

I get the following error when applying an if statement to my Google Analytics Data Get Call. Below is my code:

```
$results = $analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:' . $google_account[ 'profile' ],
  $fromDate,
  $toDate, 'ga:sessions,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:newUsers,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:goalConversionRateAll,ga:goalCompletionsAll,ga:goalValueAll',
if($gapi_primary_dimension <> ""){
  array(
    'dimensions'  => 'ga:'.$gapi_primary_dimension,
    'sort'        => 'ga:sessions',
    'max-results' => 5
  )
} else if($gapi_primary_dimension <> "" && $gapi_secondary_dimension <> ""){
  array(
    'dimensions'  => 'ga:'.$gapi_primary_dimension,'ga:'.$gapi_secondary_dimension,
    'sort'        => 'ga:sessions',
    'max-results' => 5
  )     
} else {
    array(
    'dimensions'  => 'ga:channelGrouping',
    'sort'        => 'ga:sessions',
    'max-results' => 5
    )
}
```

);

The error is coming from the first if statement (line 5). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `if/else` statements in the arguments, please try this:

```
if($gapi_primary_dimension <> ""){
  $array = array(
        'dimensions'  => 'ga:'.$gapi_primary_dimension,
        'sort'        => 'ga:sessions',
        'max-results' => 5
  );
} elseif($gapi_primary_dimension <> "" && $gapi_secondary_dimension <> ""){
  $array = array(
        'dimensions'  => 'ga:'.$gapi_primary_dimension,'ga:'.$gapi_secondary_dimension,
        'sort'        => 'ga:sessions',
        'max-results' => 5
  );    
} else {
    $array = array(
        'dimensions'  => 'ga:channelGrouping',
        'sort'        => 'ga:sessions',
        'max-results' => 5      
    );   
}   

$results = $analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:' . $google_account[ 'profile' ],
  $fromDate,
  $toDate, 'ga:sessions,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:newUsers,ga:bounceRate,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:goalConversionRateAll,ga:goalCompletionsAll,ga:goalValueAll', $array);
```

I hope this will help you.